# Run method missing in xaml class

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#

I am using F# and XAML in order to create a GUI but unfortunately after creating the type for the xaml I don't have a run method available. What am I missing here?

code :

```
module Program

open FsXaml
open System

type App = XAML<"App.xaml">

[<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let app = App()
    app.Run()
```

Comment: `App` is a ``Window``, not an `Application`. In this case, you need something like this: `(new Application()).Run(new App())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App.xaml should contain an Application, not a window:

```
<Application  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">  

    <Application.Resources>  
    </Application.Resources>  

</Application>
```

this will provide a Run method. Make sure you add a xaml file "MainWindow.xaml" with a window defined in it.

Comment: Thank you , that fixed my problem!